# ISNULL not working in CASE statement in THEN part

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having a column with NULL, which i need to replace with 0, but ISNULL is not working as I excepted.

In above picture the third output i need to replace the NULLs with zeros, can someone where am I making mistake.
Much appreciate for any suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: first of all - do not post images. Just put code to the question. According to your question, everything is working as expected, you just don't have ELSE part, and these NULLs caused by it.

Comment: sorry for that will keep that in mind. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no `ELSE` clause.  That will return `NULL` values for any other asset type key other than the ones mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

Change the underlined clause to:

```
THEN isnull(FB.ClosingBalance,0) ELSE 0 END AS LCYBalance
```